# C Code analysis with vera++

Tags: c, code-analysis, vera++

I would use vera++ to analyse several C libraries that I developed.

These libraries are contained into 4 different folders and there isn't a main.c file.

It is possible to check the libraries code with vera++? Or vera++ requires the main.c?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To check a file .c or .h run vera++ as

```
vera++ my_file.c
```

If you want to run only specific rules you can do

```
vera++ -R T013 my_file.c
```

I use the following to run vera++ on all files in src/ and include/ matching *.c and *.h

```
find src/ include/ -type f -regextype sed -iregex ".*/*\.\(c\|h\)" -print | xargs vera++
```